# XSD for XML with attributes Name, NameRus, NameEnu, NameDeu, e.t.c

Tags: xml, xsd

I show my question on real example (Autodesk company). Exists some [PackageContents.xml](http://exchange.autodesk.com/autocad/enu/online-help/browse#WS1a9193826455f5ff-4fe3487312ce8a8dba5-7feb.htm) file. But developers created a strange solution for problem with localization in it... Look [this](http://exchange.autodesk.com/autocad/enu/online-help/browse#WS1a9193826455f5ff-4fe3487312ce8a8dba5-7fda.htm) page - it is description for attributes of 'ApplicationPackage' element. Look, some attributes has such description:

> A localized [attribute name] can be specified by combining [attribute name] with a
>   locale code. See [Supported Locale Codes](http://exchange.autodesk.com/autocad/enu/online-help/WS1a9193826455f5ff-4fe3487312ce8a8dba5-7fd7.htm#WS1a9193826455f5ff-4fe3487312ce8a8dba5-7fd6) for a full list of supported
>   locale codes.

Pay attention - there the fixed set of localizations. 
i.e., for example, element simultaneously can to have such attributes: Name, NameRus, NameEnu, NameDeu, e.t.c.

Can I write XSD schema for such PackageContents.xml, but without fixed localization names?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

It's very easy for imaginative and creative people to find ways of using XML that were never envisaged by the designers of XSD. Doing so is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Michael, and thank you for your work - the Saxon XSLT processor.